# How to use AMA style in latex file?

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, texlive

I'm a newbie in latex.I have installed texlive 2014  in centos linux. I have been using apacite for bibliography. Now I need to get AMA citation style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

The above mentioned latex codes for apacite style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amacite}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amacite}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

If I run the above code to create AMA style bibliography, am getting an error "amacite.sty not found". And I don't have AMA related files in texlive. So how to download AMA files to texlive and use it in latex file. Pls help!

Comment: google returns no hits for an `amacite.bst` so it does not appear to be available in general. That does not mean it does not exist, but whichever journal submission rules said you should use that style must also tell you where to get the file from.

Comment: Then no solution for this ??

Comment: You must have got the instructions to use that style from somewhere. You need to check with them. Perhaps it was a typo and they meant apacite, perhaps it is a private style that they have, I can not guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `amacite.sty` package but there is an `ama.bst` bibtex style. It is not part of TeX Live, but you can find it  on CTAN, for instance [here](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst). You'all have to install it by yourself, in your `texmf-local` directory, more precisely in `\texmf-local\bibtex\misc\` and run `texhash`. Then use in your document:

```
\bibliographystyle{ama}
```

Comment: I downloaded ama.bst file and run the below mentioned code it works fine. Am using this code to create only a bibliography so its perfect. `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{apacite} \begin{document} \nocite{*} \bibliographystyle{ama} \bibliography{example} \end{document}` This would not be the exact solution for my question but it works like a charm.

Comment: Can someone guide a newbie on how to manually install the file

Comment: @lukeg: Aren't the explanations in the post clear enough?

Comment: I am running a window OS. I am confused with what you mean by run `texhash`

Comment: What is your distribution, MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: I am using Tex Live.

Comment: Then you should have a `texmf local` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39921/discussion-between-lukeg-and-bernard).

Comment: `ama.bst` is an obsolete file. My TeXLive complains when I try to use it: `This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3' instead`

Comment: @EA304GT: I disclaim responsability for the use of this bibstyle file.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{comma,numbers,super,open={},close={}} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section*{Latex Superscript Citation (AMA-like)}    
This is a superscript citation~\citep{da2018graph}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{da2018graph}
    Silva WMC, Wercelens P, Walter MEM et~al.
    \newblock Graph databases in molecular biology.
    \newblock In \emph{Brazilian Symposium on Bioinformatics}. Springer, pp.
    50--57.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]